# Save name instead of id from select component in laravel collective

Tags: laravel, html-select, laravelcollective

I want to save the name of a department in the table employees, in the select component it displays the name but saves the id, so I think the problem is in it.

This is the select component:

```
{{Form::select('nombre_dep', $departamentos, null, array('class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'Asignar departamento'))}}
```

In my controller I have this for returning to the view:

```
$departamentos = departamento::pluck('nombre_dep', 'id');
```

In the model for employee I have this for relation:

```
public function departamentos(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\departamentos');
}
```

I expect to save in that field for example: `production` instead of `1` that could be id of the department

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perform the pluck specifying in the `key` parameter (the second parameter), the `field` from which you want to get the value to use in the `value` attribute of the `select`.

```
$departamentos = departamento::pluck('nombre_dep', 'nombre_dep');
```

Then when you pass the `$departamentos` array to the Laravel Collective `select()`, it will create an `<option>` element for each array element, using the array `key` as `value` attribute and the array `value` as option tag content.

```
{{ Form::select('nombre_dep', $departamentos) }}
```

Answer (score 2):

The selected answer is correct, but offers no explanation.

The issue is that you create your LaravelCollective Form::select so the integer `id` is sent in the ensuing request. You can verify this by viewing the source of the Form element in your rendered blade html. It currently will look like:

```html
<select class="form-control" name="nombre_dep">
  <option selected="selected" value="">Asignar departamento</option>
  <option value="1">Production</option>
  <option value="2">Department 2</option>
  <option value="3">Department 3</option>
</select>
```

so when the action is triggered with (say) option 1 selected, your generated request simply has `"nombre_dep" => "1"`.

You need to structure your form with the desired option value. like

```html
<select class="form-control" name="nombre_dep">
  <option selected="selected" value="">Asignar departamento</option>
  <option value="Production">Production</option>
  <option value="Department 2">Department 2</option>
  <option value="Department 3">Department 3</option>
</select>
```

To do this, pass the `$departamentos` variable from your Controller like so:

```php
$departamentos = array('Production' => 'Production', 'Department 2' => 'Department 2', 'Department 3' => 'Department 3');
```

and an easy way to do that (as the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/56673741/8093282 stated):

```php
$departamentos = departamento::pluck('nombre_dep', 'nombre_dep');
```